# Unrecognized selector error processing results from geocodeAddressString

Tags: iphone, ios, clgeocoder, mkmapitem

I'm trying to create multiple placemarks using `MKMapItem` without using coordinates.

I used location name directly in `geocodeAdressString:@"Mumbai"...` but I got result for single location.

While I use multiple locations through array, I'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab48380'

Why is this problem occurring?

```
Class mapItemClass=[MKMapItem class];
if(mapItemClass &&[mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
{
NSArray *addr=[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"Banglore",@"Mumbai",@"Delhi", nil];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        CLPlacemark *geocodedPlacemark=[placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        MKPlacemark *placemark=[[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:geocodedPlacemark.location.coordinate addressDictionary:geocodedPlacemark.addressDictionary];
        MKMapItem *mapItem=[[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:placemark];
        [mapItem setName:geocodedPlacemark.name];


        [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[mapItem] launchOptions:nil];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Your calling length on an `NSArray`, `NSArray` doesn't have length they have count.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to figure out what line in your code ends up issuing this call

Comment: Please post the related code.

Comment: can any1 guide me as what mistake have i done..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error state that `-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xab48380'`
NSArray dont have a property length. So it is unable to find the selector of length. So check where you are using NSArray and keep break points to find where error is happening. length is the method of `NSString` and `NSData` but NSArray dont have length, it has count

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to replicate this using this code

```
id array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hello", @"World", nil];
NSLog(@"%d",[array length]);
```

output

```
-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96bafe0
```

notice how I have used `id` instead of `NSArray` with using `id` I am able to call `length` which isn't allowed by `NSArray`, but this gets round the compiler when using `id`.
So the best way to find out where this is going wrong is add an exception that will catch all exceptions. Do this by selecting the exceptions tab in the project navigator wind >> select '+' >> 'Add Exception Breakpoint...' >> then just select done. This will set a breakpoint every time your app throws an exception.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the code you have added I suspect that you are passing an `NSArray` where there should be an `NSString`. You create

```
   NSArray *addr=[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:@"Banglore",@"Mumbai",@"Delhi", nil];
```

then pass it to `geocodeAddressString:addr`

```
  [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
```

Just from the name of this parameter I suspect it should be an `NSString` and not an `NSArray` try replacing addr to `[addr objectAtIndex:0]` this will get the string object at index 0 of the addr array.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the method you are calling notice it only allows an `NSString` to be passed in for geocodeAddressString.

```
  - (void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

Comment: `[geocoder geocodeAddressString:addr completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {` This line you are passing geocodeAddressString an `NSArray` you should be passing a `NSString`

Comment: is it possible to pass 2 or 3 locations through NSString?

Comment: I think you will find you can only pass in an `NSString` and not an `NSArray`

Comment: Thanks Popeye..it works fine without error..but while using index value of:0..it's just displaying 1st location alone..Banglore..

Comment: is there any possible to display all 3 locations by changing in that index values??